# What is the directory structure of a C Program like?

Tags: c, program-entry-point, clion

I am starting out C programming and I could not find the answer to this anywhere.

When I run a "***.c***" file from my C project's folder, it only runs the "***main.c***" file, ignoring any other "***.c***" source files within the project's folder. So, am I correct in understanding that I can only have one source file per project, that's being run while all the others are files that are only called (i.e. #included) by that primary source file, "***main.c***"? (Similar to libraries/modules in Python)

FYI, I am using **CLion**, if this makes any difference.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The standards for C or C++ programming languages do not specify directory structures.  Directory structures are arbitrary.  I like the [Pitchfork Layout](https://api.csswg.org/bikeshed/?force=1&url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vector-of-bool/pitchfork/develop/data/spec.bs), which is but one of many.

Comment: Don't tag questions about C with C++ or vice versa (without a better reason than this question has).  It will likely earn you downvotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CLion uses CMake, you'll find a CMakeLists.txt file in your project. Any additional source files should be added (manually) to the command `add_executable(main main.c other_source.c yet_another_source.c)`. Notice these are space separated. You can have as many source files as you want!

Comment: In that case, is it a problem if (or do I need to) have a main function in each of source files? Cuz when I added the source files and ran the "other_source.c" it gave me the following error:
--->
duplicate symbol '_main' in:
    CMakeFiles/prjct1.dir/testy.c.o
    CMakeFiles/prjct1.dir/tokla.c.o
<---
Both files contain the basic HelloWorld source code

Comment: No you can only have a single main function per executable. You can have multiple executables defined in a single CMakeLists.txt file. 

So for now, as you’re beginning your journey, try to limit yourself to single projects where there’s a single executable (and a single main function).